# Replace a text by it's equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, regex, json, preg-replace

**EDIT:** I know that gettext, i18n and other stuff already exists, but this is for learning purposes.

I'm working on a way to translate my websites by using .json files that contains the wanted translations in different languages.

So I made an `index.php` that calls my class function `Parser::render($file)`, here's the unfinished code:

**home.php:**

```
<h1>{website.welcome}</h1>
<h2>{website.tagline}</h2>
<p>{website.home.introduction}</p>
```

**lang-fr.json:**

```
{
    "_lang":
    {
        "author": "ThanosS",
        "version": "0.0.3",
        "flag": "fr",
        "country": "France",
        "state": "100%"
    },

    "website":
    {
        "title": "Mon putain de site",
        "welcome": "Bienvenue",
        "tagline": "Je suis un texte en français.",

        "home":
        {
            "introduction": "Ceci est un exemple pour gérer les traductions sur un site web"
        }
    }
}
```

**lang-en.json:**

```
{
    "_lang":
    {
        "author": "ThanosS",
        "version": "0.0.2",
        "flag": "en",
        "country": "USA",
        "state": "100%"
    },

    "website":
    {
        "title": "My fucking website",
        "welcome": "Welcome",
        "tagline": "I'm a text in english.",

        "home":
        {
            "introduction": "This is an example to handle website translations properly"
        }
    }
}
```

**Parser.class.php:**

```
<?php
/**
*   Translation Example
*   @version   0.0.1
**/

class Parser
{
    private $langsPath = '';
    private $langsExt = 'json';
    private $currentLang = 'en';

    public function __construct($langsPath, $langsExt = 'json', $currentLang = 'en')
    {
        $this->langsPath = $langsPath;
        $this->langsExt = ($this->langsExt != $langsExt) ? $langsExt : $this->langsExt;
        $this->currentLang = ($this->currentLang != $currentLang) ? $currentLang : $this->currentLang;
    }

    public function render($file)
    {
        $cLang = json_decode($this->loadLangFile($this->currentLang));
        $cFile = $this->loadPageFile($file);

        $langInfos = $cLang->_lang;
        unset($cLang->_lang);

        if (preg_match_all('/{([^}].*)}/i', $cFile, $matches))
        {
            $keys = $matches[1];
            foreach ($keys as $value)
            {
                $indexs = explode('.', $value);



            }
        }

        return $parsedFile;
    }

    private function loadLangFile($lang)
    {
        return file_get_contents($this->langsPath.'lang-'.$lang.'.'.$this->langsExt);
    }

    private function loadPageFile($page)
    {
        return file_get_contents($page);
    }
}
```

I want to find a way to convert `{key.other.key}` to it's value in the current lang file (something like `<?php echo $cLang->key->other->key; ?>`)

So `Parser::render('home.php');` should return :

```
<h1>Bienvenue</h1>
<h2>Je suis un texte en français</h2>
<p>Ceci est un exemple pour gérer les traductions sur un site web</p>
```

Thanks in advance, i searched for 2 days ago but my brain isn't evolved to do that :/

Comment: Why do you reinvent the wheel? There is something like `gettext` and all its buddies...

Comment: OK, a good thing to do, indeed :-) However: in your question you stated your general approach, your goal, but you completely forgot to specify what issue you are fighting with!

Comment: The "issue" (that's not really an issue) is : "I want to find a way to convert {key.other.key} to it's value in the current lang file (something like <?php echo $cLang->key->other->key; ?>)"

Comment: @arkascha help please ? + why did you downvoted ? :(

Comment: Sorry, but I did not downvote, why do you claim so? About the issue: You repeated what you wrote in your question, but that is only a description of your goal, not what your question here is. Where is the connection between the code you posted and your question? Does it work? Does it not work? If not, what is wrong, apart from the fact, that it does not work in your eyes? you will get much better answers if you ask a clear question. Just posting some code and adding "does not work" is a post that is not much fun to answer...

Comment: It's not about "do not work", but "how to ?", i have clearly no idea of how to do this. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so your question is how to navigate inside that decoded json structure...

Here is a working example. No error handling is implemented to keep things simple. It should help you on the track :-) I left the language files and the home.php template unchanged. The following `index.php` file is just for this demo, to use your parser class below. I slightly decluttered the implementation of that parser class whilst on it. But basically the only change is that I replaced your `preg_match()` call with a direct call to `preg_replace_callback()` and coded the required dictionary navigation as anonymous function which is used as callback:

index.php:

```
<?php
require 'parser.class.php';
$parser = new Parser('./', 'json', 'fr');
$output = $parser->render('home.php');
echo $output;
```

parser_class.php:

```
<?php
class Parser
{
    const LANG_PATH = '.';
    const LANG_EXT  = 'json';

    private $langsPath = '';
    private $langsExt = 'json';
    private $langCode = 'en';
    private $langInfos = [];

    protected $dictionary;

    public function __construct($langCode = 'en')
    {
        $this->langCode = $this->langCode;
        $this->dictionary = $this->loadDictionary();
        $this->langInfos  = $this->dictionary;
        unset($this->dictionary->_lang);
    }

    public function render($file)
    {
        $rawPayload = file_get_contents($file);

        $transPayload = preg_replace_callback(
            '/({([^}]+)})/',
            function($match) {
                $matches = explode('.', $match[2]);
                $_p = &$this->dictionary;
                foreach ($matches as $step) {
                    if (property_exists($_p, $step)) {
                        $_p = &$_p->$step;
                    } else {
                        return '-- undefined i18n string --';
                    }
                }
                return $_p;
            },
            $rawPayload);

        return $transPayload;
    }

    private function loadDictionary()
    {
        // here a lot of error handling is required, probably throwing exceptions
        $langFilePath = sprintf('%s/lang-%s.%s', self::LANG_PATH, $this->langCode, self::LANG_EXT);
        $dictionaryContent = file_get_contents($langFilePath);
        return json_decode($dictionaryContent);
    }
}
```

You were pretty much there yourself, that is why I insisted in getting you to specify what your actual issue with coding this is. But I know these situations myself: nearly there, all is clear, except...  :-)

Anyways: this basically boils down to using an internal "pointer" inside the decoded dictionary. You extract the translatable strings by means of a regex in a greedy manner. Those strings are exploded into their parts of a "dot notation" (your approach). Those parts ("steps") are then used to navigate inside the dictionary by moving the pointer always one step further towards the final translated string. That's all.

Have fun!

Comment: Ah, i'll try ! I've learned pointers ! I did it differently but it works too : https://hapshack.eu/cryptpast/#!paste/813faa14 with password: `ERqzW6O8SHnpkWwOedflE13PwMr2/cGyDMYUJ6ML786jiTriEhZnfcJYoMvZlINb`

Comment: Hey, great I could help! Just a few (random) notes: 1. the signature of the constructor is strange in my eyes: why is the path to the language files an argument? It should be constant inside a project, so is a configuration attribute, not a dynamic one. 2. the loading of the language file does not belong into the `render()` method. Either it is a global thing for the project, or it is template specific, but the it should be loaded before the rendering. 3. I don't understand the `return $this;` terminating the `render()` method. But as said: these are just a few hints. Go on and have fun!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, i'll answer your notes :) : 1. The path is an argument because the langs files can be loaded from everywhere ;). 2. Yes, I have to rework that part ! ^^. 3. The `return $this;` is to make the `render()` function chainable (to render multiple views ^^) like that : `$parser->render('header.php')->render('menu.php')->render($page)->render('footer.php');` :)

Comment: To 1.) yes, obviously, otherwise the argument would not be there, BUT: _why_ should they be loadable from "everywhere"? What sense does that make? To me this sounds like there is a confusion between runtime parameters and configuration settings. 3.) sure, thought so, BUT: you buy that at a high price: the hard coded output of the renderings result without any means to handle the result, for example by filtering, except for very expensive output buffering. Not sure which is worth more, probably depends in the intended use case, so per definition you are right here ;-)